# Locking on current thread: Possible WTF?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

While looking into some old code, We came across the following code:

```
lock (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread) // Critical Section - no interrupting.
```

Our first reaction was "WTF" - the code is locking on the current thread, which is a different object on each thread (except in the case of recursion, which would just be silly to lock on, then). It doesn't seem like this lock serves any purpose whatsoever. We were wondering whether this was indeed a WTF, or whether it actually serves some purpose.

Comment: :O Wow. I'm kinda impressed by that piece of code. And horrified.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a WTF from just that line of code, but if the thread object is ever passed to other threads and used as a lock, that makes some sense.  However, using a thread as a lock seems like a pretty bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a call to `Thread.Abort` will [create a lock on the current thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/9f563da8-3d70-496d-908d-7e3f6d1cd4f4/). So it seems like this may be a way (hacky, but it probably works) of ensuring that the process is not interrupted. Of course, it's still fallible (if power goes out, for instance); but perhaps that's what it's trying to do. Of course, it would be much better to have well-defined exit points for a thread to abort. But I think that's what it's doing (`Thread.Abort` is sadly very common throughout our software).

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the code that creates the thread, and look to see where the thread object is used. Perhaps the main thread creates a number of background threads, and uses the thread objects in a lock. Or is this a threadpool thread?

Regardless, not a very nice piece of code :)

Answer (score 1):

This has no effect whatsoever except wasting CPU, even in recursion.

lock() will only provide exclusive lock per thread, so the same thread accessing an object lock for the second time will not halt. If it did you would have a deadlock situation where the thread is waiting for itself to unlock so it can continue.

```
object someObj = new object();
lock (someObj) {
    lock (someObj) {
        // this code will execute even though it had to go through two locks on the same obj
    }
}
```

Comment: it will actually run a System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier() so it does some thing but well i don't think thats the reason for the lock..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like bad practice because it can lead to unintentional synchronization. Usually you want to keep your synchronization code hidden within the scope of the class, so you would lock on non-public fields or properties.

In particular locking on

```
this
```

or other object available by public static API such as

```
Thread.CurrentThread
```

is a bad idea, because it is easy for the user of your library to mistakenly lock on the same object.

The reverse is also true, if you have a threadsafe object avoid locking on the object itself (because it may be locking on 'this' internally), instead use a dedicated object. If it is necessary to synchronize from outside the class the dedicated object can be made public. An example of this is

```
ICollection.SyncRoot
```